# How to move the horizontal line beneath the title?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put the horizontal bar beneath the text title where is inside of the container `<div>` but the horizontal bar just effect in the width, but not moving up to the position...

I am hesitating that should I create one more div. I have been trying to move up the `hr` by top with `vh` or even `margin`, but that is not workable.

What I want is to move the `hr` below the title.

[How I want the hr to move up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmV3H.png)

[Original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtqmY.png)

```css
.topcon {
  background-color: #f6f5f5;
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 15px;
  padding: 50px;
  margin: 180px auto 150px auto;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.pattern-card {
  position: relative;
  right: 50px;
  border-radius: 20px 20px 0px 0px;
  bottom: 50px;
}

.victor {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 3px solid #ffffff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-right: auto;
  bottom: 110px;
  width: 50%;
}

.user-name {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30%;
  left: 20vh;
  top: 40vh;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  font-family: "Kumbh Sans", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #2d3248;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.user-age {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20%;
  right: 15.5vh;
  top: 40vh;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  font-family: "Kumbh Sans", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #969696;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.user-location {
  position: absolute;
  width: 25%;
  left: 22.5vh;
  top: 45.5vh;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  font-family: "Kumbh Sans", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #969696;
}

hr {
  border-top: 1px solid #969696;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 50vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="topcon">
  <img class="pattern-card" src="images/bg-pattern-card.svg" alt="pattern card at the frame." />
  <img class="victor" src="images/image-victor.jpg" alt="image for Victor" />
  <p class="user-name">Victor Crest</p>
  <p class="user-age">26</p>
  <p class="user-location">London</p>
  <hr /> 80K Followers 803K Likes 1.4K Photos
</div>
```

Comment: can you update your code with all the relevant css

Comment: You may not need a horizontal rule element at all. Check **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66091215/4512005)**, as an alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also dismiss the horizontal ruler (line) entirely, and use CSS `border-top`. I tried and got this:

```css
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}
body * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.card {
  width: 300px;
  height: 320px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
  -moz-border-radius: 8px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.11);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.11);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.11);
}

.card-header {
  height: 105px;
  background: #44d3d9;
}

.card-image {
  margin-top: -50px;
}

.card-image img {
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
  border: 4px solid #fff;
}

.card-content h2 {
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.card-content h2 span {
  color: #6d6d6d;
  padding-left: 6px;
}

.card-content .location {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #6d6d6d;
}

.card-footer {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: auto;
  height: 90px;
  border-top: 1px solid #efefef;
}

.card-footer > div {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border-right: 1px solid #efefef;
}

.card-footer > div:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

.card-footer ul {
  margin: auto 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.card-footer ul li {
  color: #6d6d6d;
  font-size: 11px;
}

.card-footer ul li.count {
  color: #111111;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header"></div>
  <div class="card-image">
      <img src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/91.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="card-content">
    <h2>Victor Crest <span>26</span></h2>
    <p class="location">London</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card-footer">
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li class="count">80K</li>
        <li>Folowers</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li class="count">803K</li>
        <li>Likes</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li class="count">1.4K</li>
        <li>Photos</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this

```
hr{
  border-top: 1px solid #969696;
  margin-left: -50px;
  width: 350px;
 margin-top: -15px;
}
```

change the `margin top` and `width` and `margin left` according to your div width and height